# CSS 2.2 spec calculate height of inline replaced height

Tags: css

I was reading today the section [10.6.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height) from [10.6 Calculating heights and margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins). I do have some questions regarding the below statement:

> Otherwise, if 'height' has a computed value of 'auto', but none of the conditions above are met, then the used value of 'height' must be set to the height of the largest rectangle that has a 2:1 ratio, has a height not greater than 150px, and has a width not greater than the device width.

A. What if there is no largest rectangular box which has `2:1` ratio?

B. Why this `2:1` ratio and height of `150px` is considered as **standard** ?

Comment: Why not 150px? These elements must have _some_ default height. Ort do you have ideas for a better height? (For those not inclined to follow the link, 10.6.2 is about elements like iframe, object etc.)

Comment: By the way, there are more such standard sizes. The 40px indent of list items springs to mind. All these amounts are specified in the official docs to provide some default for browsers to adhere to, for cross-browser compatibility purposes.